# PDF vazio ao efetuar o download utilizando Spring Boot e AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, pdf

Estou criando uma aplicação onde preciso retornar um PDF através de uma chamada de API desenvolvida em Spring Boot através do AngularJS, o meu código está como o abaixo:

Retorno da API:

```
ResponseEntity.ok()
        .headers(result.getHttpHeaders())
        .body(new InputStreamResource(result.getInputStream()));
```

Onde o header é **application/pdf**

Código AngularJS:

```
$http.get("path/pdf", 
    { params: params },
    { responseType: "arraybuffer" }
)
.then(function(response){
     console.log(response.data);
     var blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});            
     FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'arquivo.pdf');
});
```

Como resultado o PDF gerado pelo FileSaver fica em branco, mesmo o **response.data**, estando os dados.

Ao chamar a url da API diretamente pelo browser o PDF é retornado normalmente.

Comment: Já tentou trocar o `responseType` pra `blob` e chamar direto `FileSaver.saveAs(response, 'arquivo.pdf')` ou `FileSaver.saveAs(response.data, 'arquivo.pdf')`?

Comment: Sim já tentei, o FileSaver.saveAs recebe uma instância de Blob ao mudar acontece um erro, e mudando apenas responseType o pdf continua vindo em branco.

Answer (score 1):

Problema resolvido alterando o método no **AngularJS**:

```
$http.post(mobioneEnvService.addPath("/operation/report/alerts/export"), 
           params, 
           {responseType:"arraybuffer"})
     .then(function(response){

            var blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});

            FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'report.pdf');
     });
```

A API deve aceitar também chamadas através de POST.